# Read previous page url in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages

First.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function()
            {
                document.getElementById("firstForm").submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="Second.aspx" method="post" id="firstForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnField" id="hdnField" value="hello" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second.aspx.cs file: (writing code behind)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //section 1
    }
    else
    {
        //section 2
    }
}
```

**First.html** can recide anywhere outside my web application and I can not change its code. I need to read the complete url of **First.html**.

How can i read it and in which section should I?

I try to read with

```
string prevUrl = Convert.ToString(Request.UrlReferrer);
```

but the above line is returning empty string

Please help.

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` usually gets information about the URL from where the request has been made and it's one time activity as soon as page is refreshed it will return empty url.

Comment: I am not refreshing the page, still getting empty string, I tried using document.referrer of js, but again empty string. I don't know why it is going to section 2, though it is loading first time.

Comment: it's going in section 2 because as soon as your page is loaded you are submitting a form. It's obvious it will take you to section 2 and may be due to this you have lost `Request.UrlReferrer` information

Comment: One of the reason of getting null in Request.UrlReferrer is that, the user is coming from a secure site. In my case, First.html is placed at a secure site. visit [ASP.Net Forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1101617.aspx?Request+UrlReferrer+is+always+null).